# focusing on a contenteditable body in an iframe on load

Tags: javascript, iframe, contenteditable

This is working fine in Firefox and IE, but I can't get this to work in Chrome:

```
self.editorIframeDocument.body.focus()
```

`editorIframeDocument` == `contentDocument` || `contentWindow.document` depending on the browser.

`.body.focus()` makes it so when the editor loads I can start typing right away. Perfect, however, in Chrome it's not working. I tried hooking into the iframe as well as the iframe `#document` but no go.

I saw some hacks with setting a selection and removing it, but they were all examples in a `<div>` `contenteditable` with specific HTML inside not an `<iframe>` which could have anything from nothing to large amounts of text.

***No jQuery.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the editor wasn't loaded yet so Chrome wouldn't let me focus on it. Checking for ready state fixed the issue:

```
if (self.settings.focusOnLoad) {
  // We need to wait until all three iframes are done loading by waiting until the parent
  // iframe's ready state == complete, then we can focus on the contenteditable
  self.iframe.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
    if (self.iframe.readyState == 'complete') {
      self.editorIframeDocument.body.focus();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: When were you trying to call focus before? I think I've previously addressed this with a timer or something.

Comment: I was calling it outside of the readystatechange listener. So, it'd check if the option was set and run the focus code, but because the element didnt exist yet to Chrome, it couldn't focus.